# Setting timeout jQuery.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have an event that when clicked initiates a jQuery load().  The load passes several MB of POST data.  I am getting aborted errors.  How can I set the timeout?

```
 toggleModalLoading();
 $("#ele").load('http://site.com/script.php',{
               'data' : postData },
                function(e) {
                      toggleModalLoading();
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

The `.load()` call is really just a convenient shorthand. You could [set global ajax options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) before the `.load()` call. If that's not viable, you'll have to use [the lower-level API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Either way, you want the `timeout` ajax option:

```
$.ajax('http://site.com/script.php', {
   data: postData,
   timeout: 1000, // 1000 ms
   success: function (data) {
       $('#ele').html(data);
       toggleModalLoading();
   } 
});
```

Comment: Sure. Anything is possible. Wire up an `error` handler and see what's going on.

Comment: Just did.  console.log("Text is: " + text + "Err is " + err); in my error: function(jqXHR, text, err) {} function.  I am getting "Text is error" with no status code.

Comment: The server can handle the request as I manually POSTED the data.  jQuery is choking

Answer (score 2):

set the timeout for the Ajax calls.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 30000
});
```

If the server is causing it to stop, look at the settings in the php ini file.

Comment: Yes, did you look at the error returned? Did you change the ini file to handle larger files?

Comment: I set the max post size, max upload size, and execution time well above the limits.  Still an issue.  It's not a file in terms of multipart/form-data.  It's a base64 encoded string that is 10MB.